# Why maven meta-data doesn't include specific version of all artifacts

Tags: maven, metadata, maven-plugin

I have a lot of artifacts which gets uploaded to different nexus managed repositories, and many of my artifacts have at some point a release version ending with XX.Y.0.0, that is, ending with 0.0. I have tried many times, but maven meta-data xml files doesn't include these versions. The xml meta-data files includes versions before and after, but never this specific versions.

Does any of you have any idea why, and hopefully have solution for that? I have tried deleting the meta-data xml files, and tried rebuilding using nexus, but nothing happens.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcing Nexus to rebuild the metadata. Sometimes it gets corrupted.

Maven treats versions such as 1.2.3.0.0 as equal to 1.2.3.

For more details on the Maven versioning scheme, check [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Versioning).

Comment: I have tried that, but all the *.0.0 versions doesn't show up. I have also deleted all the *.xml files and rebuild them, still no success :-(